# How to handle server validation/errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm dipping my toes into Blazor Server and I'm really unsure about how I should handle messages from the server back to the client in the event of an error or some server side validation. My brain instantly thinks "use a viewmodel", but is this the right answer?

I have this model:

```
public class Season
    {
        public int SeasonId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Season Description")]
        public string SeasonDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        public bool Publish { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a `Season` repository:

```
public interface ISeasonRepository
    {
        public Task<List<Season>> GetSeasons();
        public Task<Season> GetSeason(int SeasonId);
        public Task<Season> UpdateSeason(Season season);
        public Task<Season> AddSeason(Season season);
        // TODO: Implement Delete
    }
```

And, I have this service that is injected to my page:

```
public class SeasonsService
    {
        private readonly ISeasonRepository _seasonRepository;
        public SeasonsService(ISeasonRepository seasonRepository)
        {
            _seasonRepository = seasonRepository;
        }

        public async Task<List<Season>> GetSeasons()
        {
            return await _seasonRepository.GetSeasons();
        }

        public async Task<Season> GetSeasonById(int SeasonId)
        {
            return await _seasonRepository.GetSeason(SeasonId);
        }

        public async Task<Season> UpdateSeason(Season season)
        {
            return await _seasonRepository.UpdateSeason(season);
        }

        public async Task<Season> AddSeason(Season season)
        {
            return await _seasonRepository.AddSeason(season);
        }
    }
```

Previously using MVC, I would be creating a viewmodel and probably passing a message to it if we had any server logic that indicated if our model failed any server side validation/logic or if we had an error.

How is it best to handle this with Blazor? Should I still be using viewmodels? I've read about `ErrorBoundary` but it feels like they're for more critical problems that might cause SignalR state issue.

I can't get my head away from viewmodels but hardly any examples I read use such flow. How can I best notify my users the logic failed or there is something such as a SQL concurrency issue?

Comment: I’ve read this article today which seems to satisfy my needs. Still really can’t find any best practice information though. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/mvvm-pattern-in-blazor-for-state-management.aspx

Comment: I am working this days to a blazor application and I decide to use IMediator and CQRS pattern, and I am facinated about IPipeBehaviour, where you can run code before or after a request. I use a PIPE for validating request and raise toast notifications with meesages about the status of the request. It's incredible how easy it is. Ifound a lot of tutorials on youtube about Mediator and CQRS.

Comment: '' Previously using MVC, I would be creating a viewmodel and probably passing a message to it if we had any server logic that indicated if our model failed any server side validation/logic or if we had an error. '' Do you mean you use ViewModel to show the  server side validation error ? And why not just use view to show the error ?  Does  the [Required] attribute not show ' Something  is required. ' when you do not  write something?  Do you want to show  server side validation error ? I am not clear about the best practice information you want. Could you give me an example ?

Comment: *I'm really unsure about how I should handle messages from the server back to the client* - what do you think is the "server" and the "client" in a BSS app?

Comment: Blazor Server runs on the server so your ViewModel approach works just fine.  If your looking for versions of the Blazor bible you'll find one here:  https://github.com/hassanhabib/The-Standard.  I personally use a "light" version of this approach.

Comment: @LucianBumb - Looks interesting. I will read more about it.

Comment: @QingGuo The example could be that model validation passes on the client but whilst processing the CRUD there is something that fails - concurrency for example. I want to relay this back to the user.

Comment: @CaiusJard My understanding is that anything processed on the page is effectively the client and anything the other side of the "submit" (CRUD operations for example) would be logic processed on the server.

Comment: What does *processed on the page* mean? I find it easier to think of a Blazor Server app as like VNC or Remote Desktop; the server runs the app, the app forms HTML as it runs, it sends just the diffs in HTML (between what it last generated and what it just now generated) to the client, the client patches the HTML diffs into its DOM and thus the user sees changes. The whole process is thus a remote control an app that runs on the server; the browser draws the app based on HTML instructions it receives over a SignalR link. You don't specifically communicate with the client at all..

Comment: ..the only thing that leaves the server is a stream of HTML that will cause changes in the browser rendering but it isn't your concern; forming HTML at the server end is your concern and working out what parts of HTML to send to the user, so they see something representative of your formed page, is Blazor's problem. The client side needs precious little intelligence beyond being able to run a small bit of javascript that patches the diffs into the page, like remote desktop clients need little intelligence other than to render a bitmap they get from a server that has screenshotted its screen

Comment: @CaiusJard I guess you're right with regards to my client/server analogy when referring to the DOM and the server. I guess what I'm trying to do is effectively inform the DOM about errors/validation messages from the server once a database operation has completed and do it efficiently. Using view models seems the best way to me, but I'm a bit of a one trick pony, so to speak. I wondered if there was a better way, being new to Blazor. I do appreciate the RD analogy though, it made me think somewhat differently about the architecture.